# How to set subcontrol properties via XAML, if its not possible via style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to set properties of a subcontrol in a usercontrol.

The `LabeledTextbox` user control is defined as:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="cLabel" Content="{Binding Caption}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cTextBox" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="cUnit" Content="{Binding Unit}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is what I want to do when using that control:

```xml
<!-- how to set only cLabel Width? something like: -->
<local:LabeledTextbox cLabel.Width=100>
```

I guess its not possible via styles, cause style would also set `cUnit`. Right?

I tried styles, but it sets all subs.

Comment: Since LabeledTextbox seems to be your own control why not define your own dependency property and use this how ever you like?

Comment: but then i have to set DPs for every DP in the subcontrol... so now i only want to set width, but then i want to set MinWidth... there must be a general way... not?

Comment: Okay, I see. In that case I would work with resources. Give your label a style pointing to a dynamic resource if the resource is defined it will be applied. define it at <local:LabeledTextbox.Resources> …

Comment: ok, that would work, but if you define application wide default label styling, that would be lost. you have to set BasedOn to the appwide style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the resources of that element to set those properties, and then use a Trigger to define which element you want to set the properties for. In your case, that would be
`<Trigger Property="Name" Value="cLabel">`

```xml
        <local:LabeledTextbox>
            <local:LabeledTextbox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="cLabel">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </local:LabeledTextbox.Resources>
        </local:LabeledTextbox>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to set that value for multiple of those controls, you can wrap the chunk of stuff you want to isolate in some sort of container control and set the resources for that containing element. This is particularly useful if you have a lot of these controls and some more complex styling:

```xml
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="cLabel">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple" />
                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:LabeledTextbox />
            <local:LabeledTextbox />
            <local:LabeledTextbox />
        </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: it seems you missed the problem with that approach OP tried to highlight. by specifying a style targeting ALL label the style would be applied to both labels in use, those with the name cLabel AND cUnit. BUT OP only wants to style the label cLabel.

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed that.

Comment: @RandRandom, thanks for the clarification there. I updated my answer to better address the OP's question. Also I made some suggested edits to the OP's question that I think would help others as well.